# Nested page router outlets height not adjustable (ios)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using [this example](https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng) that has nested page-router-outlets. I discovered that the nested router will always take 100% percent of the page height on iOS, while on Android it will obey what you tell it.

For example, if you did something like this the nested page-router-outlet will be the full height on iOS but on Android it will actually be 400 tall

```
<GridLayout rows="400, *">
    <GridLayout row="0">
        <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
    </GridLayout>

    <GridLayout row="1">
        <Label text="Some other content"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I have used this in one of my project and it worked fine, only difference was I have given explicit heigh to page-router <StackLayout row="0" height="400">
        <page-router-outlet name="catoutlet"></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground ?

Comment: I do not know how to make a playground quickly from an existing project. If you just clone that link I attached before then in `/src/app/tabs/tabs.component.html` add a GridLayout row to the tab layout and set the page-router-outlet to a set height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working perfectly fine on ios well. There may be some other issue with your code only. As suggested by you, I have cloned the github code and added that to playground for your to test. You can access the playground from [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=R0nIK4&v=3).

What I would suggest is to add your child in above playground and test. May be that child component has 100% height that would be overlapping the parent.

Comment: Your routing was not correct, it was not loading the tab page. [Look at this version I made](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HyUzi5&v=5) In "player/players.component.html" there is a label that is aligned to the bottom, but you cannot see it because the parent item overlaps it.

Comment: I have just changed GridLayout to Stack in Players.component.html and can see both the labels. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=HyUzi5&v=6

Comment: I still believe it is working normal, may be I am not getting what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, StackLayout solved it. Thank you. In the most recent link I sent it was behaving differently on iOS and Android, so I'm not sure what is nominal behavior.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. Rule of thumb is most f the times You need to set height in ios explicity to make it work.

Comment: It is a good pratice to mark answer as accepted once you have the answer so that people don't spend time to read Q&A and then get to know that post is answered. I can see there are many such posts in `nativescript` tag.